# Get json array object value using $.each

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/r981u2sq/) is the structure of my JSON:

```
[{
    "industry": [{
        "Supermart": [{
            "merchant": [{
                "name": "Lazada",
                "banner": "abc.com/img.jpg",
                "url": "http://lazada.com.my"
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        "apparel": [{
            "merchant": [{
                "name": "fashionvalet",
                "banner": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/572008219506003968/SEB35DFb.png",
                "url": "http://lazada.com.my"
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        "Electronics": [{
            "merchant": [{
                "name": "Rakuten",
                "banner": "http://kpisland.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/RakutenMalaysia.jpg",
                "url": "http://www.rakuten.com.my/"
            }]
        }]
    }]
}]
```

How can I get the industry array obj value? like `supermart`, `apperal` and `electronics`?

```
//ajax callback
success: function (data) {
    data = JSON.parse(data);

    $.each(data.industry, function (index, obj) {
        console.log(this[index][0]);
    });
},
error: function () { 
});
```

I tried `console.log(this[index])` it returned undefined, or my json structure is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

data is an array so `data[0].industry`

```
$.each(data[0].industry, function (index, obj) {
    var key = Object.keys(obj)[0];
    console.log('Key',key);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/eqty6d3z/)

Comment: so complicated, should i redo my json structure?

Comment: @AaronMusktin if that is an option then yes

Comment: where should it be simplify? it's industry -> merchants -> merchants detail.. I think I made it to be complicated, can u help?

Comment: in using $.each(), what is the diff btw `this` and `obj`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

```
data.industry[index]
```

or just obj returns the value.